# Definition of "hard process" in QCD

Tags: particle-physics, terminology, quantum-chromodynamics

In QCD electron-positron annihilation there is often the talk of **hard processes** and I am not a 100% sure about the definition of this term.

Does **hard processes** simply refer to all processes in the region of a small coupling constant $\alpha_s$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard processes are those in which the momentum transfer, $Q$, is substantial with respect to the QCD scale, 
$$Q > \Lambda_\text{QCD}\simeq 220 \,\text {MeV} .$$
In this regime, the strong coupling constant $\alpha_S$ is perturbative. In contrast, non-perturbative effects in soft emission requires complicated techniques (e.g. showering).

Comment: ΛQCD is approximately 330 MeV.